# Scraping JS-fueled webpages with python 3.x on windows computer

Tags: javascript, python

This is my first post here, so I hope you'll be kind enough to point out my mistakes if ever I crossed any rules of this website.

First off, I'm quite "self-taught" in both english and python, so I apologize in advance if I make any language mistakes.

So, I'm learning Python as I said, and I was trying to write a script able to scrape a webpage to get an element of it so that it continues to the next link, and so on. On my different attempts, I sometimes stumbled on a webpage whose interesting link is generated by a script (most certainly JavaScript), and so, when the webpage is retrieved by requests.get(url) doesn't contain the link I'm interested in (while I see it in my web browser while Inspecting the page or viewing source code.

I KNOW there is the Selenium solution, but I was wondering if there was ANOTHER way. I found several, but none I actually got to make work. I've tried with dryscrape, which I found out, isn't supported on Windows computers.

Any hint on what direction I should direct my research at?
Again, I'm hoping for a solution without using selenium, that works on Windows computers.

**EDIT:** Oh, seeing as the answers suggested that already, I probably should have mentionned that my code uses requests and BeautifulSoup already. Problem is, neither deals with javascript that modifies the source code directly in the client. When I try to scrape the webpage in question with BeautifulSoup, many tags (including the one I'm interested in) don't appear in the whole page. It appears JavaScript injects some code when the page is loaded within the browser. In any case, there is no occurence of the link I'm after in the webpage I point requests.get at, nor in the requests.get(url).text I am looking in with BS4.

Thanks folks :)

Answer (score 0):

There are already full solutions out there like [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/).

Instead going that route, I'd recommend you give it a shot to libraries like [lxml](http://lxml.de/) and [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)

Comment: I already use requests to get the url I'm wanting to scrape, yet as I noted (a bit late) in my EDIT, the portion of code I'd love to scrape _does not_ appear when I use requests.get(url). Is there something I'm missing? Oh and when using BS4 (which I do), I use html.parser. Do you think using lxml might change anything? If yes, how so?

Comment: @ChuckC I have had several issues using BS4 few years ago dealing with broken html while that lxml has been rock solid for me

Comment: I'll give it a go if there is no other way (BS4 is already implemented big time in my script, and I'm trying not to rewrite the entire thing). Thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: @ChuckC Not saying BS4 is bad though, it's just in my experience isn't as solid as lxml. If you're already using it and it works... why not?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you try [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

Comment: Thanks, Andy. I tried that already (though, I did not mention it in my original post). I should have said so from the beginning, sorry.
Do you think that BS can still be the solution, now that I explained things a little more precisely in my EDIT? If yes, how so?